# Unity Vuforia Hololens Development access Network Share Folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, uwp, hololens

I have developed a Vuforia Hololens Application which will load a model in at runtime once I have scanned an image target. This is fine if the model is apart of the project itself but I want to be able to grab the model from a network share. I have found on the asset store a OBJ Importer which does the job and works fine when running the application on a pc. The problem arises when I come to run it on the Hololens and it does not have permissions to access that network folder. I need to pass in the credentials some how. The only solution I have found is to impersonate a windows logon and pass in the credentials which also works fine on a pc. I cannot then deploy this to the Hololens as the assemblies used do not exist in an UWP application. I tried to create a .NET Class library and then import the DLL into the Unity project. Again this works fine on a pc but it will not deploy to the Hololens as I guess it is struggling converting the .Net Assemblies.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried granting `Everyone` the `Read` permission on the folder ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Yes I have granted Everyone and Guest full permissions to the folder. I have just tried connecting to it on my phone. It wouldn't allow me at first I had the enter my PC's windows username and password to be able to get to the folder. Its like I need to connect to the network share but pass through a username and password? But this seems weird considering it is open to everyone?